# Get time with distanceText. and JSON ,

Tags: java, json, android-studio, duration

Im using JSON and textView to get the duration of the trip , my question is that , when you request a trip , these calculate the duration and distance ,  for example
: 1 h 22 m
[0][1][2][3] //
22 min
[0][1]
but if the duration of the trip is less than a hour, just minutes , the price of the cost is 0 , i know is because i put the position[2] in the minutes.What can i do? i want when trip is more than a 59 min, minute get position [2] and when is less than a hour get position [0].

in this part of code is fine if the trip is > 59 min,

```
    private void drawRoute(){
    mGoogleApiProvider.getDirections(mOriginLatLng,mDestinationLatLng).enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {
            try{
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response.body());
                JSONArray jsonArray =  jsonObject.getJSONArray("routes");
                JSONObject route = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
                JSONObject polylines = route.getJSONObject("overview_polyline");
                String points = polylines.getString("points");
                mPolylineList  = DecodePoints.decodePoly(points);
                mPolylineOptions = new PolylineOptions();
                mPolylineOptions.color(Color.DKGRAY);
                mPolylineOptions.width(13f);
                mPolylineOptions.startCap(new SquareCap());
                mPolylineOptions.jointType(JointType.ROUND);
                mPolylineOptions.addAll(mPolylineList);
                mMap.addPolyline(mPolylineOptions);
                JSONObject distance = leg.getJSONObject("distance");
                JSONObject duration = leg.getJSONObject("duration");
                String distanceText = distance.getString("text");
                String durationText = duration.getString("text");
                mTextViewTime.setText(durationText + " " + distanceText);

                String[] distanceAndKm = distanceText.split(" ");
                double distanceValue = Double.parseDouble(distanceAndKm[0]);

                String[] durationValueHoursAndMin = durationText.split(" ");
                double durationValue = Double.parseDouble(durationValueHoursAndMin[2]); 
                double durationValueHours = Double.parseDouble(durationValueHoursAndMin[0]); 
                calculatePrice(distanceValue, durationValue,durationValueHours); 
            }catch (Exception e){
                Log.d("Error","Error encontrado" + e.getMessage());
            }

        }

            private void calculatePrice(final double distanceValue, final double durationValue,final double durationValueHours) { //  agregue durationValueHours y modifique todo aca
    mInfoProvider.getInfo().addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.exists()){
                Info info = dataSnapshot.getValue(Info.class);
                if (durationValueHours >= 1){
                    double totalDistance = distanceValue * info.getKm();
                    double totalDurationMin = durationValue * info.getMin();
                    double totalDurationHours = durationValueHours * info.getHours();
                    double total = totalDistance + totalDurationMin+totalDurationHours;
                    mTextViewPrice.setText("S/." + total);
                }
                else{
                        double totalDistance = distanceValue * info.getKm();
                        double totalDurationMin = durationValue * info.getMin();
                        double total = totalDistance + totalDurationMin ;
                        mTextViewPrice.setText("S/." + total);
                }

            }
        }
```

[enter image description here][1]

in this image you can see the price with hours minutes and with just minutes
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CM9OO.png

Comment: What language is this?  C++?  Please put in question's tag area.

Comment: It's java, I just put it

Comment: Thank you!  Sorry I can't help you - good luck!

Comment: When you call ```split(" ")``` on ```17 mins```, ```String[] durationValueHoursAndMin``` will have only ```2``` elements.  So ```durationValueHoursAndMin[2]``` will cause an Exception.

Comment: Yes , thats why price is 0 when is minutes. What can i do to when is more than a hour , take like the code of top , and when is less than a hour , 
double durationValue = Double.parseDouble(durationValueHoursAndMin[0]);// take positon 0  i try an if but it doesn't work